# How to execute a Java main class using @Configuration in a gradle project right after the beans are created

Tags: java, spring, gradle

I have a config class that instantiates all the beans. I have a main class 
TestUpdator() with an execute().
I plan to run this main class when I do a "gradle tomcatRunWar" to run the war which will generate the beans and run the execute() in the main class.
Example.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "<packageName>", excludeFilters = { @Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = Service.class) })
@EnableSolrRepositories(basePackages = "<solrPackageName>", multicoreSupport = true)
public class JobConfig {

   private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JobConfig.class);

  @Bean
  public SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory() throws Exception {
    ....
  }

  @Bean
  public SpringContextAware springContextAware() throws Exception {
    .....
  }

  .....

  //MAIN CLASS BEAN TO BE EXECUTED
  @Bean(destroyMethod="shutdown")
  public TestResultUpdator testResultUpdator() throws Exception {
    TestResultUpdator resultUpdator = new TestResultUpdator();
    /**
       Bunch of dependencies for this bean
    **/
    resultUpdator.execute();   //call to execute()
    return resultUpdator;
}
```

The TestUpdator class looks like this

```
public class TestResultUpdator {
   //Variables

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        //NOT SURE WHAT TO ADD HERE SINCE THE execute() will be called from the class above. But this is what I have right now commented out.
        //      ApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(JobConfig.class);
        //      TestResultUpdator updator = appContext.getBean(TestResultUpdator.class);
        //      updator.execute();
    }

    public void execute() throws Exception {
         logger.info("INSIDE EXECUTE FOR TEST UPDATOR!!!!");
         while(true) { 
            //CODE TO BE EXECUTED  
         }    
   }
}
```

This class will execute in the background and would be executing code when the war is run.

Is there a way to do it the way I have it or is there an alternate way? 
I have googled around and am not able to find good examples of this.

Basically what I am trying to do it two things,
1) when I do gradle tomcatRunWar, it will start tomcat and deploy the war
2) when it does that it should run the main class (TestUpdator) in the background by calling the execute()

Answer (score 0):

Well, unless you're developing is a Spring Boot project, term main class is meaningless here.

If you're trying to execute a piece of code in TestResultUpdator class during context initialization, you can follow these steps:

1 Organize `TestResultUpdator` class as follows:

```
@Bean
public class TestResultUpdator {

@PostConstruct
public void execute() {
        //CODE TO BE EXECUTED  
   }
}
```

2 Get this bean somewhere in your code:

```
@Autowire
private TestResultUpdator bean;
```

Comment: You are right about the main class being meaningless.